# ¿Cómo saber si una entidad JSON es un objeto anidado con la librería node.js de C++?

Tags: c++, nodejs

Estoy haciendo un `addon` para `nodejs` en el cual tengo una función en `c++` que recibe un solo argumento desde `javascript`, ese argumento es un objeto literal con formato `JSON`, el cual ya en `c++` obtengo la `clave-valor` y los imprimo en la terminal.

Miré [esta página](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533193/v8-c-how-to-get-object-key-values-provided-as-arguments) en la cual hay una respuesta que me ayudó a obtener cada `clave-valor` del objeto recibido desde `javascript` e imprimirlo en la terminal.

El código esta algo así:

```
void printKeyAndValue(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info){

    v8::Isolate* isolate = info.GetIsolate();

    if(info.Length() != 1){
        isolate->ThrowException(v8::Exception::TypeError(
            v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Se esperaba 1 argumento.")));
        return;
    }


    v8::Local<v8::Context> context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();
    v8::Local<v8::Object> object = info[0]->ToObject( context ).ToLocalChecked();
    v8::Local<v8::Array> props = object->GetOwnPropertyNames( context ).ToLocalChecked();

    for(int i=0, l=props->Length(); i < l; i++){
        v8::Local<v8::Value> local_key = props->Get( i );
        v8::Local<v8::Value> local_value = object->Get(context, local_key).ToLocalChecked();

        //Aquí la variable 'local_value' contiene el valor asociado a una 'clave'

        std::string value = *v8::String::Utf8Value( local_value ),
                    key = *v8::String::Utf8Value( local_key );

        std::cout << "Clave: " << key << " : " << value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

¿Como puedo saber si la variable `local_value` también es un objeto en que se pueda iterar e imprimir también sus valores?

Este es la función de `javascript`:

```
//Es un ejemplo
dbm.printJSON({
    uno: 1,
    objeto: {
        letra: 'a',
        array: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        objeto: {
            nombre: 'usuario'
        }
    }
});
```

Por el momento si el valor de una propiedad es un objeto, este se imprime como `[object Object]`.

Gracias desde ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré [esta página](http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1Value.html) con una lista de métodos de un `v8::Value`, solo necesitaba usar el método `IsObject()` de la variable `local_value`.

Solo necesitaba algo como esto:

```
if(local_value->IsObject()){
    // ...
}
```

De igual manera gracias.

Comment: Si esta respuesta soluciona tu problema te agradeceríamos la marcases como solución. Un saludo

Comment: Eso haré, solo que puedo aceptar mi propia respuesta en 2 días.

Comment: Perfecto. Como eres relativamente nuevo en SOes simplemente pretendía asesorarte